# How to take part of matrix if unknown number of dimension in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

Suppose I want do something similar to

```
image(1:end-1,2:end,:)
```

which here is taking part of colored image

but with unknown number of dimensions, i.e. which will work automatically like

```
image(1:end-1,2:end)
```

for 2 dimensions

```
image(1:end-1,2:end,:)
```

for 3 and

```
image(1:end-1,2:end,:,:)
```

for 4 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to take all of the 3rd dim and up, you can use

```
>> image(1:end-1,2:end,:,:,:)
```

even for 2D array.

Alternatively, you can use `subsref` for a less ad-hoc/hacky approach:

```
>> [S.subs{1:ndims(image)}] = deal(':');
>> S.subs{1} = '1:end-1';
>> S.subs{2} = '2:end';
>> S.type = '()';
>> subsref(image, S )
```

Comment: Shai offers a solution to a MATLAB problem that *doesn't* use `bsxfun`!? :)

Comment: @DangKhoa don't forget I have a background process that runs `bsxfun` in a loop (a vectorize loop) - so every solution of mine has `bsxfun` (and even that rhymes;)

Answer (score 0):

I would have two ideas for this case.

**1st way:**
You could reshape your image before, e.g.

```
% transform image to 3d format
% do not forget to transform all used entities to this 3d-format as well
sizeIm = size(image);
image3 = reshape(image,[sizeIm(1:2),prod(sizeIm(3:end)])

% work on image3
image3(1:end-1,2:end,:) = ...;

% transform back:
image = reshape(image3,sizeIm);
```

**2nd way:**
Could be a solution to use `eval` and `repmat`, e.g.

```
eval(['image(1:end-1,2:end',repmat(',:',[1,length(size(image))-2]) ')'])
```

Depends a little bit on what you are using it for (setting, getting, ...).

Comment: -1 For the eval. The code is already not simple to read, with `eval()` is gonna be a nightmare.

Comment: Wow... that's "fair"! It is just one suggestion. Do you know where and how exactly he want's to use it?

Comment: I down-vote `eval()` solutions in 99% of the cases (I will update in the future my description as to why).

Comment: I know lots of arguments against `eval` on my own, nevertheless I gave 2 more or less useful answers which you don't have to upvote of course, but a warning comment with arguments against the 2nd way would have been more than enough.

Comment: The reshape on the other hand is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array `A`:

```
A  = rand(2,3,2,5,7);
```

Then, you can fill with `':'`, the remaining dimensions of your selection:

```
nd   = ndims(A);
subs = repmat({':'},1,nd-2);
A(1:end-1,2:end, subs{:})
```

Answer (score -1):

I have there a little idea. You can formulate a function, that analyse the dimension of your Matrix with `size(size(Matrix),2)`. Then you are able to construct a string, that contain your desired command with a little for loop and after this you execute this string with eval.

```
A=rand(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3) %<--- change here dimension

dim=size(size(A),2)

addstr='';
if dim>2
    for i=1:dim-2
        addstr=[addstr ',:'];
    end
end

command=['A(1:2,1:2' addstr ')']

eval(command)
```

Comment: Hey, I have posted this 15 minutes ago in one line. I suppose Oleg will downvote you soon ;-)

Comment: @matheburg you are so right. Because I think it isn't such a bad idea i vote you up again ;-)